# why ant design doesn't load CSS in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, antd

I making a frontend with a react and ant-design but I have problem
there is no error but page look like html without CSS
and I use layout component

that is what I use: https://ant.design/components/layout/ (Header-Content-Footer)

npm version: 6.14.9
nodejs version: 14.15.3

here some code :

src/index.js :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";

import App from "./app";

class CustomMain extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <App />;
  }
}

ReactDom.render(<CustomMain />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

src/app.js :

```
import React from "react";
import CustomLayout from "./containers/Layout";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <CustomLayout />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

src/containers/Layout.js :

```
import React from "react";
import CustomLayout from "./containers/Layout";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <CustomLayout />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "gui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "antd": "^4.9.4",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're missing an import.
Make sure you added `import 'antd/dist/antd.css';` in the `index.js` file.

You can look for more info here:
https://ant.design/docs/react/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred after react-script was upgraded to 5.0.0 solution :

```
- import 'antd/dist/antd.css
```

replace with :

```
+ import 'antd/dist/antd.min.css
```